# What are the steps to switching Drupal website/server to HTTP2

Tags: drupal, http2

We need to convert our Drupal website to HTTP2.  What would the steps be needed to convert the website and server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Turn it on in your web server in dev.
2. Test it to make sure no unintended consequences - nothing should have to change at an app level to use HTTP/2 as the web server and browser takes care of all that for you automatically (one of the many nice things about HTTP/2!), but there can be unintended consequence due to removal of download constraints. See here as an example: https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2019/04/10/why-turning-on-http2-was-a-mistake/
3. Decide if you want to optimise for HTTP/2 (e.g. bundle and sprite less) to get most out of the new protocol.
4. Turn it on in your web server in prod.
5. Monitor and measure impact.

Comment: Hi, what are those download constraints you are refering to?

Comment: Previously you could only send 6 requests at once and, given the browser prioritised them, the most important 6 were sent at once, followed by next important, followed by...etc. With no limits (or at least very high limits of 100 -120) everything can go at once, and maybe lower priority requests will end up slowing high priority requests and you see a performance regression.